# Log-in control if username is not found the label text should answer username not found

Tags: asp.net, connection

got a few question here. As you all know ive created a class wherein ill just instantiate it on my .aspx page.On my .aspx page ive got a logincontrol named login1. Now im getting error when user.UserName = Nothing and stop on this `user.UserName = Nothing` saying `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`.Could you help me debug the problem. All i want is that if the username is not on the database the lblmessage should say **Error Username is invalid** and if it is correct then it will check on the password. Please do help. Thanks and more power guys.

Aspx page

```
    Protected Sub LoginButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim user As New User
    Dim userDAL As New UserDAL
    user = userDAL.SelectByUsername(Login1.UserName)
    If user.UserName = Nothing Then
        Login1.FailureText = "Invalid Username"
    Else
        If Login1.Password <> user.Password Then
            Login1.FailureText = "Invalid password"
        Else
            Login1.FailureText = "success"
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

UserDAL.vb

```
 Public Function SelectByUsername(ByVal userName As String) As User
    Try
        'select * from User where Username = 'userName'
        Dim sqlConn As New SqlConnection(_connString)
        sqlConn.Open()

        Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand("select * from [Users] where Username = '" & userName & "'", sqlConn)

        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()

        'Create user collection
        Dim user As User = Nothing

        While dr.Read()
            'Create User object
            user = New User
            user.UserName = dr("UserName").ToString
            user.Password = dr("Password").ToString
            user.FirstName = dr("FirstName").ToString
            user.Surname = dr("Surname").ToString

        End While
        dr.Close()

        Return user
    Finally
        If _sqlConn IsNot Nothing Then
            If _sqlConn.State = Data.ConnectionState.Open Then
                _sqlConn.Close()
            End If
        End If
    End Try
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of comparing with `user.Username`, first you compare with only `user` i.e.,

```
If user Is Nothing Then
```

Why Bcoz in your `SelectByUsername` function you are returning `Nothing` if it is invalid username. Try it and reply.

Comment: sir it is still the same Object reference not set to an instance of an object. now pointing at If user.UserName = String.Empty Then

Comment: now sir ive got an error saying Operator'=' is not define for types 'User' and 'Users'

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the simplest answer on this.  Add a validation Summary to your control that returns the required value ("Username Not Valid") and then in your code to validate do a

```
if(Page.IsValid) (This is C# code but VB should be very close to this)
```

That should solve your problem.

Here's a quick snippet

```
       <asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
       <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="User Name Not Valid" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Now of note this error message would display to the right of the text box, however you can style it or even set it to a validation group.

The required field validator or validation group with a validation summary forces client side validation with ASP.NET for postback so when the submit button fires it will run a test and determine if Page.IsValid == true or false;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx